# Scrapy ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'dict'

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have tried reproducing the Scrapy tutorial using Xpath and keep running into `ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'dict' in <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/>` Not sure how to fix this.

I'm going to share snippets from two files which should be just enough for debugging:

1) My spider `quotes_spider.py`

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy import Request

class QuoteSpider(Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            yield {
            'text': quote.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract(),
            'author': quote.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/text()').extract(),
            'tags': quote.xpath('.//div[@class="tags"]/a[@class="tag"]/text()').extract(),
            }
```

2) `items.py`

```
from scrapy.item import Item

class QuotesbotItem(Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()
```

FYI: In case you compare this to the [tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and are wondering why I switched the `extract_first()` to `extract()`, it's because I was seeing another error `exceptions.AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'extract_first'` which is unrelated to this question I believe.

Comment: What version of Scrapy are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a dictionary as the error says and not an Item

```
class QuoteSpider(Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
        item = QuotesbotItem()
        item['text'] = quote.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract()
        item['author'] = quote.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/text()').extract()
        item['tags'] = quote.xpath('.//div[@class="tags"]/a[@class="tag"]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Well, `dict ` is a supported type indeed - see [the code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/eb5d396527c2d63fa6475dfd9b6372a19bce5488/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L184).

Comment: Yeah i thought it was usable because of https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1064. `pip list` tells me my version is 0.24.4